# Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a modul

Tags: javascript, html

У меня есть 3 файла: index.html, index.js и comp.js

Так вот я хочу импортировать объект из comp в index но выдает ошибку

> `Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

вот код:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Framework</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Framework, hello world!</h1>
    <script src='index.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
import myComponent from './comp.js';

console.log(myComponent);
```

comp.js

```
let myComponent = {
    'text': 'tdtfdtfd'
};

export default myComponent;
```

Answer (score 7):

> ```
> <script src='index.js'></script>
> ```

```
<script type="module" src='index.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

`import` можно использовать внутри модулей. У тебя модулей нет, используй `require`.

```
const MyComponent = require('./comp.js');
```

Comment: require не работает с модулями, скорее всего.

Comment: Вопрос же про ESM, а `require` это синтаксис CommonJS...